# How do you make a user go to another page using the input they used?

Tags: php, redirect

how can I make it so a user is directed to a certain page based on the input they put into an input area?

For example, a domain is www.google.com/user.php?u=

If the user inputs: Jack

How can I make it redirect them to: www.google.com/user.php?u=Jack

So the "Jack" part is added onto a certain URL and automatically redirected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take input from user and make use of `header()` to redirect.

```
 <form action='redirect.php' method='post'>
      <input type='text' name='user'>
 </form>
```

redirect.php

```
    <?php 
         if(isset($_POST['user'])) {

                $user =  $_POST['user'];
                $url = "http://www.google.com/user.php?u=";  
                header("Location:".$url.$user);
          }
     ?>
```

Comment: `$url = "www.google.com/user.php?u=";` that will fail, and should include the `http://` prefix. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: You're welcome TIntu, *cheers*